# Accessing Azure MySQL service

Tags: mysql, azure

I'm having problem trying to access the MySQL server (I'd like to replace a table with another) provided as part of the Windows Azure service. I have downloaded the publishsettings XML file, and the closest thing that I can find is 'Data Source=us-cdbr-azure-east-a.cloudapp.net;'. However, it's not accessible from the web browser, so I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Which tool are you using to connect to the database? PHPAdmin or something else? Also check if the firewall settings are open to be able to be connected to. SQL Azure doesn't allow it by default so you have to explicitly turn it on for outside connection. Didn't try this one out yet with MySQL but I bet the same way of thinking has been used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the full connection string from the dashboard of your Azure Web Site

[image: Dashboard of your Windows Azure Web Site]

[image]

Then you can use those credentials in a MySQL administration program, such as [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: Update myself. In my case, this only work for the database linked with web application . It's not working if I create a new SQL database independently.