# How to manage mysql databases created in Azure?

Tags: mysql, azure

Azure websites let us configure our site using a new MySQL Database instead of SQL Azure. But after creation it's never visible in admin panel. I beleive that it's because is hosted in a third party server, but I have no idea how to reach it, any tip?

Comment: so after the free trial do you inherit the clearDB pricing model? 1gb mySql db for 9.99 a month? Seems pricey. the link from the terms links to this which indicates it's hosted by heroku. http://www.cleardb.com/pricing.view#heroku

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For managing it from an external tool [check out my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111760/accessing-azure-mysql-service/12112187#12112187).

Though the database is hosted by a third party (ClearDB), you should see it listed as a "linked resource" on the dashboard for your Web Site in the Windows Azure portal. When you delete the Web Site, it asks if you also want to delete the linked resource.

If you choose not to or you unlink the MySQL resource explicitly, it's still there and you'll see it a list of existing resources when you subsequently do an explicit link.  (I haven't found a way to see a list of the unlinked MySQL databases, but will update this response when I hear).

So I'd say to delete the MySQL database you can

1. Delete the entire Web Site and, when prompted, select the MySQL database to be deleted too
2. Unlink the MySQL database from the Web Site you want to keep; create a new temp Web Site, and add the existing MySQL database as a Linked Resource to it. Then delete the new, temp Web Site along with the linked database.  Not elegant, but seems to work in my testing.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Erasing the website prompted me to also erase the database, thanks!

Comment: I deleted my database wrongly and it didn't appear in linked resources anymore. Is there a way to restore the database again?

Answer (score 4):

Currently you can't manage the MySQL Server.

As for being third party - yes, the service (MySQL-as-a-Service) is provided by a third party byt lives in Azure! It is not on other servers, it is on the Azure servers. Most probably (just my guess) worker roles. But as the feature is still preview, the management is missing.

The third party vendor is [ClearDB](http://www.cleardb.com/partners). They provide MySQL as a service on top of Windows Azure. so no worries, your data is in the same Data Center (of course if you chose same) as your web site. But you can't directly manage it, unless you install something like [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) on your website.

Comment: I deleted my database wrongly and it didn't appear in linked resources anymore. Is there a way to restore the database again?

Comment: no, if you delete your database it is gone. you may try opening a support ticket for that, but I doubt there will be any result.

Comment: I opened a ticket to ClearDB and they restored my DB.

Comment: But the clear Db is very BAD! it only has mysql 5.5 ( so my structure would need ot be changed and code, due to mysql 5.5 bugs) ... And.. They dont support Triggers and Views! :( IM moving to Amazon

Comment: With phpMyAdmin, a microsoft azure account is required.

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different issue where Jim O'Neil's #2 didn't fully work because the database that was orphaned was created through the "Add-On" gallery. To work around this, you can link the orphaned database to the new temporary site as suggested, and then click on the "Manage" link in the Linked Resources tab with the database selected. This will take you to ClearDB's management for the databases.

From there, you can click on the first tab, and then click "Delete" to manually delete the database from ClearDB. This is an async operation so it may take some time, and you may also have to refresh the portal because the entries are cached.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the ClearDB Add-on and create either the Free tier or the 9.99 a month Venus 1gb tier. The Free tier is only 20mb so that isn't much. For the database name, you can type in the existing MySQL database, and ClearDB Add-on will link to that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old question, but it's the first result that came up when I did a Google search for deleting mysql azure databases.  You *can* manage your MySql databases from the management portal now, via the Linked Resources page.  Either click on the name of the mysql DB directly, or select the row and click manage down at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

i know that this is a late answer but i followed them to gain the exact access

1. Select Your web app
2. Clicked linked resources
3. Click on mysql db name (It will redirect you to cleardb website for your account)
4. Install mysql workbench
5. click on endpoint information
6. in mysql workbench give the value of hostname, and access credentials i.e. username, password

and you are good to go :)