# Mysqli support on windows azure cloud?

Tags: php, azure, mysqli

I was impressed by the pricing for microsoft's azure cloud platform and want to switch. However, I have 976 php scripts that are written in mysqli. There was not a clear answer if it was or was not supported. Is it? And if not, are there any other similar cloud services that support mysqli?

Comment: Did you bother to read [faq]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the biggest things about Azure is the ability to use open source software vs proprietary M$ software.

See:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/community/open-source-software/

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-w-mysql-and-git/

[How to manage mysql databases created in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190067/how-to-manage-mysql-databases-created-in-azure)

Comment: So I only need to change the database connectivity settings for my mysqli to work...

Comment: yes, see second link in list. PHP is enabled by default, so just setup your MySQL database and your code will work.