# MySQLi not available on Windows Azure Websites

Tags: php, azure, mysqli, azure-web-app-service

Since the beginning of last week, I have started recieving the following message in my logs:

```
[26-Jun-2013 03:00:08] 1. Try to dump database …
[26-Jun-2013 03:00:08] ERROR: No MySQLi extension found. Please install it.
[26-Jun-2013 03:00:08] 2. Try to dump database …
[26-Jun-2013 03:00:08] ERROR: No MySQLi extension found. Please install it.
[26-Jun-2013 03:00:08] 3. Try to dump database …
[26-Jun-2013 03:00:08] ERROR: No MySQLi extension found. Please install it.
```

The software stack is:

- Windows Azure Websites - 2 Instances, Shared
- PHP 5.3
- ClearDB MySQL
- Wordpress 3.5.1
- BackWPUp 3.0.12

Nothing has been upgraded within the timeframe of experencing this error, and backups were completing successfully before the beginning of last week.

Is it possible to enable MySQLi on Windows Azure?

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504085/mysqli-support-on-windows-azure-cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you echo `phpinfo();` you would notice it is installed... I have a [listing of defaults](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2012/07/19/getting-started-with-php-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) admittedly out of date, but still valid except for additional support or version upgrades.

Alternatively, you could [BYO Runtime](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2012/09/13/enabling-php-5-4-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) or use app settings to [enable PHP Extensions in Windows Azure Web Sites](http://windowsazurewebsitescheatsheet.info#enable-php-extensions)