# Azure: Where is default user/pass for Wordpress database using MySQL in-app(preview)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, pdo

I just started an Azure hosted WordPress App Service and chose to do the MySQL in-app(preview) option for the database. For those that aren't aware, this allows me to run the MySQL server side-by-side with my Web application within the same environment.

However, I'm running into a problem with the way I am choosing to make MySQL queries.

I want to reuse code from a different PHP project where the MySQL calls are in the form of PDO statements, like so:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localdb;charset=utf8',
                    'user',
                    'pass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "did not connect...";
}

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT *FROM MyTable;");
$sth->execute();
```

I can't make these calls unless I have a username and password to do so.

The PHPMyAdmin side-panel looks like this in the MySQL in-app(preview):

[image: PHPMyAdmin side-panel for MySQL in-app preview]

And if I pull up the user accounts, this is what I see:

[image: PHPMyAdmin User Accounts]

I'm lost when it comes to what user and pass I should use, and if I should even be using `localdb` as my db (that's where all the wordpress tables are listed).

All in all, I'm just trying to pull information from the database using PDO statements and need to know how to go about it.

Comment: I assume Azure offers a control panel to list your services. If so, it should show the host/IP of the database - otherwise this info should be visible in phpMyAdmin. As for credentials, create a new account in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12112187/472495) help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The connection string can be seen in `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt`. You can locate this file through Kudu Debug Console which could be accessed via `https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

The file content looks something like:

```
Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1:54306;User Id=azure;Password=6#vWHD_$
```

Following is a sample code snippet using PDO to connect MySQL in-app.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=localdb;host=127.0.0.1:54306;charset=utf8';
$user = 'azure';
$password = '6#vWHD_$';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!";
```

---

### Important update:

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4c582216-bc1b-48b0-b80b-87ae540c3d05/php-azure-mysql-inapp-changed-ports-randomly

> A VM can host multiple WebApps; hence multiple in-app MySQL processes. When we start MySql process, we attempt to use the same port as before. However, it may be taken by other service or other in-app MySQL. As a result, the port may change. In addition, web app can be moved from one VM to another and the set of available ports will be different.
>
> In order to write the stable client app, do make sure you read the connection info from env variable. See [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki#where-can-i-find-mysql-credentials-connection-string) for more details.

So we should get the connection string from env variable in PHP like below:

```
$connectstr_dbhost = '';
$connectstr_dbname = '';
$connectstr_dbusername = '';
$connectstr_dbpassword = '';

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }
    
    $connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);
}
```

Comment: Nail on the dot and then some! Perfect solution, great code example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go to Configuration then add connection

Name = defaultConnection
Value = Database=your_database;Data Source=your_website.mysql.database.azure.com;User Id=your_username;Password=your_password

then for me suresh42326 answered worked

> For me, visiting .azurewebsites.net solved my issue. after
>   that I browsed .scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin, it didn't
>   ask password.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2238#issuecomment-427358981

Answer (score -1):

```
/*Add at the begining of the file
if you want to connect to custom database then fill this variable  $connectstr_dbname = 'MY_CUSTOM_DB'; and comment or remove  $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value); from below code...
*/

$connectstr_dbhost = '';
$connectstr_dbname = '';
$connectstr_dbusername = '';
$connectstr_dbpassword = '';

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);
}

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', $connectstr_dbname);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $connectstr_dbusername);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', $connectstr_dbpassword);

/** MySQL hostname : this contains the port number in this format host:port . Port is not 3306 when using this feature*/
define('DB_HOST', $connectstr_dbhost);
```

Comment: Why did you just copy and paste the answer above?

Comment: read top comments it explains how you can connect custom database. i faced this problem and then solved it. so i thought it will be help full for others.